# nasm keyboard driver I/O

Tags: assembly, x86, keyboard, driver, nasm

I wrote a small NASM kernel, set up the IDT, remapped the PIC and PIT and masked all interrupts except for IRQ1 keyboard. I want to make a keyboard driver which prints the characters input by the user. I tried following tutorials but I'm just confused and don't know where to begin. I know there's a control port (0x64) and a data port (0x60). I tried following approach:

```
irq1_h:                  ;irq1 handler
    pusha                ;save registers by placing on stack
    sti                  ;restore interrupts
    in al, 0x60          ;read input charcter from keyboard data port 0x60
    mov [string], al     ;save it in string
    mov ebx, string      ;print string character
    call print_string
    popa                 ;get registers back
    mov al, 0x20         ;send End of Interrupt to PIC
    out 0x20, al
```

When I run the code everything works fine until I press a key. I get the Exception Fault Bounds Check (exception nr.5, my own programmed error screen). I run this in QEMU. Apart from this everthing works well.

**EDIT:** Adding a `ret`at the end stopped the crashing. The characters printed are not the ones typed though, because I have to translate the scan codes from the keyboard to ASCII characters?

Comment: Where is your `iret`? Also, check your exception for the cause.

Comment: @Jester The handler is called CALL instruction by a function the IDT points to . The iret is in that other function.

Comment: @KlausMaria Oka.  Then where's your `ret` to come back from `irq1_h`?  The code looks like it just falls off the end.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in this function and trace execution.  If you can't do that, use a better debugging setup, e.g. BOCHS with its built-in debugger that knows about segmentation and stuff.

Comment: @fuz you were right I needed a ret at the end but it prints characters not corresponding with the keys I pressed. My actual question is if the concept as a driver is ok.

Comment: @KlausMaria I'm not 100% sure.  Kindly fix the code in your question to have the required `ret` instruction so others won't get caught on this detail and can instead focus on your actual problem.

Comment: After you fix the `ret` be aware that the keyboard controller returns scan code, not ascii characters. you have to do the conversion yourself. It depends on the scancode set you are using. You can find more here: https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard

Comment: Enabling interrupts (with STI) before you process the character is probably a bad idea if you explicitly haven't written your code to be re-entrant.

Comment: @Michael_Petch thank you very much, I will definitly take a look at how to convert the scan codes to ASCII. You were all very helpfull. It might not be a bad idea to write an answer :)

Comment: @fuz thank you too for the tip about `ret` at the beginning.